# To view PDBs from HR schema

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I have installed Oracle 12c R2 on my local machine and have created the `HR` schema using this link : [Installing sample schemas](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC109.)

I also gave `GRANTS` to `HR` schema to view data dictionary.

```
GRANT SELECT ANY DICTIONARY TO HR;
GRANT SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE TO HR;
```

Now, when I connect  as `SYSDBA`, I am able to view PDBS.

```
SQL> select con_id, dbid, name
     from v$pdbs;

    CON_ID|      DBID|NAME
----------|----------|------------------------
         2|3752719039|PDB$SEED
         3|3679838824|ORCLPDB
```

However, when logged in as HR, it **does not** show anything.

```
SQL> select con_id, dbid, name
    from v$pdbs;

no rows selected
```

I surely have connected to the same instance.The output of this query is same for both connections.

```
SQL> select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','INSTANCE_NAME') instance  FROM DUAL;

INSTANCE
-----------------
orcl2
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the user is a common user connected to the root container.

A common user's [CONTAINER_DATA](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/authorization.htm#DBSEG803) attribute determines which PDBs are visible in container data objects

```
SQL> alter user c##hr set container_data=all container=current;

User altered.

SQL> conn c##hr
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> select name from v$pdbs;

NAME
------------------------------
PDB$SEED
ORCLPDB

SQL>
```